# Using a single firebase http function for all request types?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Like many others, I'm struggling with cold starts for most of my cloud functions. I did all the optimization steps that the documentation recommended, but because almost all of my functions are using the admin SDK, and Firestore, a typical cold start takes around 5 seconds, meaning that the user has to wait at least 5 seconds for the data.

I'm thinking on replacing all my http trigger cloud functions with a single one, like `/api/*` and set it up to have some amount of `minInstances`.

What are the cons of this approach? What is the point of having multiple http functions in the first place?

**TL;DR; Why shouldn't I use a single http cloud function for my REST like api to handle all the resources in order to eliminate cold starts?**

Answer (score 0):

> **Why shouldn't I use a single http cloud function for my REST like api to handle all the resources in order to eliminate cold starts?**

Because this won't eliminate cold starts. In fact, you will be loading a bigger function every time you invoke your /api/* root function.

As in the example from this [video](https://youtu.be/rCpKxpIMg6o), the point of having multiple functions is to instance them as needed, and also to be isolated between them.

To [reduce cold starts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#min), you could set

> a minimum number of instances that Cloud Functions must keep ready to serve requests. Setting a minimum number of instances reduces cold starts of your application.

See also:
[Cloud Functions Cold Boot Time (Cloud Performance Atlas)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY)